# How to create file upload with pure js and the FileReader API

Tags: javascript, forms, file, filereader

I'll try my best to describe my problem.
Basically, I'm building a forum webapp. Recently I began trying to implement the functionality where, when a user signs up, he / she can choose a photo from his / her local file system. Then, when the user signs up, the image file should be read via the `FileReader` API in client-side JS, set the value of the file input to the image URL, then submit the form.
Now, I'm not trying to directly upload the file into a separate image. I'm just seeking to save the data URL in my database. Many people recommend using **Multer** for the file upload, but unfortunately, I've already deployed a long time ago and have programmed some changes in the GH repository, so installing npm packages is not an option.
What doesn't work: the value doesn't change and the URL uploaded is only the name of the image file (e.g. shark.jfif).
I've looked online but found nothing. Here's my client-side JS code in case you're wondering.

```js
const file = document.querySelector('input[type="file"]').files[0];
const fReader = new FileReader();
const imgName = fReader.readAsDataURL(file);
document.querySelector('input[type="file"]').value = imgName.result;
```

Ideally, I would use an event listener to check when the value of the input file changes but I'm not sure what kind of event would be ideal. Definitely not submit, as this code takes a while to execute and the filename would already be saved to the database. The value doesn't change with my current code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually did something very similar a few years ago, and turned it into a tiny JavaScript 'library': [cropper.js](https://www.billy-brown.net/cropper.js/). This has slightly more functionality, as it allows you to crop the image before uploading it anywhere, so it actually goes: file input -> canvas -> img. Here however, we will cut the canvas step out.

The idea behind it is to get the data URL from the FileReader, and when it is loaded, set it as the `src` attribute of your `img` tag:

```js
const img = document.getElementById('img');
document.getElementById('fileInput').addEventListener("change", e => {
  const file = e.target.files[0];
  const reader = new FileReader();
  // Read the image as base64 data
  reader.readAsDataURL(file);
  // When loaded, use the file data
  reader.onload = (e) => img.setAttribute('src', e.target.result);
});
```

```html
<input type="file" id="fileInput" />
<img id="img" src="" />
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, and this would have worked if I only wanted to display the image on the page temporarily, but instead I'd like to store the URL in a database. This idea could be further extended though in theory.

Comment: @expressjs123 When you say store the URL, do you mean some HTTP URL to the image, or the data URL that is generated? Notice the `reader.onload` line, which is the event listener for when the image has been loaded.

Comment: Oh wait I found out the problem the console was throwing an error

Comment: @expressjs123 At the time, this script was part of a PHP page, that would then save the image to disk on the server, then upload the path to that image to the database, in case that helps. (If I remember correctly.)